# javascript: is the File object immutable?

Tags: javascript, file, object, properties

In coffeescript I have this code, which is trying to extract GPS info from an image:

```
 EXIF.getData this, ->
                lat = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude")
                long = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLongitude")
                alert(lat)
                alert(long)
                file.lat = lat
                file.lng = long
                console.log(file)
```

The alerts show me that the lat and long values are present, but it does not get stored in the the file object.
The console log output is this:

```
File { size: 95923, type: "image/jpeg", name: "pic1.jpg", path: "", lastModifiedDate: Date 2014-12-04T16:05:37.000Z, mozFullPath: "/home/me/Pictures/pic1.jpg" }
```

Is the File object somehow immutable / read-only as a javascript object? Am I missing something?

I know that Files are sensitive and all properties are read-only, but I am surprised one cannot change a File object to add own properties...(it it so)
So somehow the

Comment: _all properties are read-only_ Well, that tells you pretty much everything, doesn't it?

Comment: File objects are *host objects*, which can pretty much behave however they want.

Comment: Which browser are you using, Firefox? What console are you using? Have you tried simply accessing `file.lat`? File objects are extensible, I guess you only were fooled by the log.

Comment: @Bergi you are right! alert(file.lat) shows me the value! Why would the console.log ignore it? Actually I found out that lat and lng are arrays...maybe that's the reason?

Comment: I have no idea, but being arrays should not be a reason. Maybe it somehow distinguishes between native properties, or that created from the constructor, and those that were added afterwards. Also try expanding ("inspecting") the logged object, I'm pretty sure you'll see them there.

Comment: @Bergi if you wish so please provide an answer and I will accept it, your comment brought me to the path of solving my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `File` objects are not immutable. You can always extend them with new properties.

It seems like you have been fooled by your console. For some reason it didn't output the `lat` and `lng` properties, but you still will be able to access them on your object. Also try expanding ("inspecting") the logged object